# auto grow depending on content and center (centre) absolute div in middle of page

Tags: css

This code centres the div in the middle of the page

```
#divMessage {
    z-index: 500;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

but the text goes over the div if the text is too long for it without the div expanding and without the background increasing.

an overflow:auto will enable scroll bars but this also is not an acceptable solution for me, how do I keep the div centred but enable it to grow?

**Update:**
If I use min-height:100px the div goes from the top to the bottom of the screen due to my top 0 and bottom 0 that I use to centre the div in the middle of the screen, again this is not an acceptable solution for me.

:-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the heigth property, it's fixing it, and then change it to min-height. This way the div will remain the size you want if there's no text, and it will grow as desired.

Tweak to work in all browsers:

```
 #divMessage { 
     min-height:100px;
     height:auto !important;
     height:100px; //this should be the same as min-height.
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately if I use min-height the div goes from the top to the bottom of the screen due to my top 0 and bottom 0 that I use to centre the div in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using auto margins to center your div, try playing with the left and top positions and left/top margins; The trick is to put it 50% from the top and 50% from the left and give a negative left margin equals to half of the div width. The same goes to the top margin.

Example:

```
#divMessage {
    z-index: 500;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VtAcB/

Like this you can set the min-height CSS property, as suggested by @EricFrick.

**UPDATE**

Indeed, the content wasn't making the container grow as needed, only to some point. After giving this a try, I found out that there is no way to make it the way you want. The min-height only changes the initial height, but when it overflows, the div stops growing. It seems this is a behavior common to absolutely positioned elements.

A workaround: continue to set the min-height just like the previous example, changing the values and set overflow-y: scroll or overflow: auto; to #divMessage. But remember to adjust the top margin as you change the box min-height, or you won't have a vertically centered block anymore.

Updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/VtAcB/1/

About the positioning issue you pointed, note that in the fiddle the example is centered properly, there is something in your code that is preventing the div to center. I bet there is something related to the div that contains it in your project. Remember that elements that have position: absolute gets its position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to the containing block. Check your container div width and height with chrome dev tools or firebug to see its dimensions.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get the desired results with this either.  It isn't properly centred in the middle of the page and when the content grows the text goes over the div without the div growing.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @TwistedInferno I made some changes to the answer, take a look. Hope this helps.